# Angular - How to avoid multiple http calls in canActivate

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular App with two authGuard Services:

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AccountService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.identity().pipe(
      map(account => {
        if (account) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
        return false;
      })
    );
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class StartupService implements CanActivate {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  constructor(public auth: AccountService, public router: Router, private sidebarService: SidebarService) {}
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.identity().pipe(
      switchMap(account => {
        this.isAdmin = account.isAdmin;
        return this.sidebarService.getCompanies(account.id.toString());
      }),
      map(firms => {
        if(this.isAdmin && Object.keys(firms).length === 0) {
          this.router.navigate(['startup']);
          return false;
        }
          return true;
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }
}
```

In the AuthGuardService I call the identity service for checking if I'm logged or not, if not I need to redirect to the welcome page; in the StartupService I invoke the same service and I also check if I'm admin and I have some data available (companies). I also invoke the same service in the ngOnInit in the AppComponent and with ngrx I save the account state in the store. I invoke the same service for three times. Which is the best way to avoid this situation? Where can I use ngrx selector? I see in the debug that canActivate is invoked before the ngOnInit AppComponent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    public auth: AccountService
    public router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.identity().pipe(
      map(account => {
        if (account) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
        return false;
      })
    );
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class StartupService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private auth: AccountService,
    private router: Router,
    private sidebarService: SidebarService
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.identity().pipe(
      switchMap(account => this.sidebarService.getCompanies(account.id.toString())
        .pipe(
          map(firms => {
            if(account.isAdmin && Object.keys(firms).length === 0) {
              this.router.navigate(['startup']);
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          }),
          catchError(() => of(false)) // you probably also want some redirection on error
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your setup more important is how you have implemented `AccountService.identity`
If it returns some observable that has current state of user identity something like this:

```
class AccountService {
  identity$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

  identity() {
    return this.identity$;
  }

  authenticate() {
    this.http.post('/authentication').subscribe((identity) => {
      this.identity$.next(identity)
    })
  }

  logout() {
    this.identity$.next(null)
  }
}
```

It will call HTTP only if you call authentication and your user identity will be stored in `identity$`

Comment: NIce!! But In this way in the canActivate can I use only the identity function that returns me the identity observable?

Comment: @Andy88 yes but you can go even further and hide all logic inside canActive behind some access control service "canAccessResource" method and just react to its result when you want to redirect